Text decoration no longer applied to In post links
First, I am new to having a website and far from an expert though I am trying to learn every day.
I am struggling with the in-text links I have in my posts, they no longer have any text decoration. They were set to a different text color (a brownish color) and I believe at one point underlined.
Now the in-text links look the same as all other text in the post.
The theme I use has Kadence blocks for editing.
I have attempted changing the text link decoration through Kadence but it doesn't change in post links (only homepage or header links).
I have cleared the cache on my computer and my website.
Through research, I tried adding an Additional CSS code into the Kadence style editor using the following:
.post a {

text-decoration: underline!important;

}

I have resorted to manually changing each and every link in some posts, but I don't want to have to do that for each and every post.
Website: https://rejoiceabout.com/
Example post that has in-text links with no decoration: https://rejoiceabout.com/how-to-make-diy-wooden-house-number-sign/
Is there something I am missing? Again, not super knowledgeable about backend/coding but willing to try with some guidance!
If there is a simple approach I would also love to hear it.
Thank you!

there's a text decoration none important but it's impossible to see where it's coming from as all your stylesheets are hidden behind a caching layer. While that's in place it'll be impossible to track it down just by looking at the site unless a full copy of the code is provided which would never fit in your question. Note that your question also needs to contain everything needed to answer it you can't rely on 3rd party links, they can support it but they can't be the question/answer

Using !important is generally not recommended, as it leads to problems like this where styles can't be overridden and a site becomes an unmaintainable mess. Your stylesheets are absolutely littered with !important: I count 909 instances. Instead of using !important you should override styles by supplying a rule that's more specific.
You can find out where the offending style is by disabling your cache then inspecting a link using your browser's dev tools, it will tell you which file and which line to look for.

As you can see, the line number on the right refers to line number in the cache. With the cache disabled, that line number will point you to the original file and line so you can edit it.

Thank you for the response. Where does the !important come from? The theme itself? I have only added the one in additional CSS, as listed in my original post so I don't know how the rest got there or what they are doing.  What should I be looking for in the dev tools?

We don't know where it comes from because you have a cache enabled. Once you disable that you'll be able to see what line and file the declaration is coming from (I've added a screenshot to my answer).
